# OpenLayers 3 Image and Text style zindex

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

I've noticed that text and image styles don't seem to respect their layer order when being rendered. For example, when many features with these styles are close together, all the text is rendered on top of other overlapping vector features. Is there a way to disable or override this behavior? Thanks.

```
myFeature.setStyle(new ol.style.Style({
  image: new ol.style.Icon({
    src: '/images/myImage.png',
    anchor: [0.5, 1],
    anchorXUnits: 'fraction',
    anchorYUnits: 'fraction'
  })
}));

myOtherFeature.setStyle(new ol.style.Style({
  image: new ol.style.Circle({
    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
      color: 'rgb(255,200,77)'
    }),
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
      color: 'rgba(0,0,0,.2)',
      width: 1
    }),
    radius: 14
  }),
  text: new ol.style.Text({
    font: 'light 10px Arial',
    text: '1',
    fill: new ol.style.Fill({color: 'black'}),
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({color: 'black', width: 0.5})
  })
}));
```

Comment: See this discussion: https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/issues/1876

Answer (score 2):

When stacking point symbols with text, you need to give every point its own (increasing) zIndex if you want the text to stick to the symbol. See http://jsfiddle.net/8g1vayvc/. You can also do that in a style function:

```
var myStyle = new ol.style.Style({/*...*/});
var zIndex = 0;
function styleFunction(feature, resolution) {
  myStyle.setZIndex(zIndex++);
  return myStyle;
}
```