# Openlayers text style is over all other elements

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, styles, openlayers

I've made a  style for my features, with an fontSymbol "marker" as ol.style.image, and a font awesome icon as ol.style.text
My issue is that my style has normal zIndex, but the text style (truck icon) is over all other elements.

[image: see image :]

Here is the code

```js
this.iconLayerStyles.iconStyle = new ol.style.Style({
      //  marker icon shape
      image: new ol.style.FontSymbol({
        form: 'marker',
        offsetY: -24,
        radius: 25,
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
          color: '#4CAF50'
        }),
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
          // color: 'white',
          color: style.outlineColor ? style.outlineColor : 'black',
          width: 1
        })
      }),
      // marker icon symbol
      text: new ol.style.Text({
        text: '\uF0D1',
        font: '900 20px "Font Awesome 5 Free"',
        offsetY: -26,
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
          color: 'black' // or white
        })
      }),
      zIndex: 100
    })
```

Whenever I set new position for my features, I update the style depending on props of each feature.

Here is where I set the zIndex of my style  :

```js
this.iconLayerStyles.iconStyle.setZIndex(icon.id)
```

I also update setImage() etc ..

I know we can only set zIndex on global style, but why the hell is the text style having this behaviour ?
Note that only the truck (as text style) is having a strange behaviour, all others elements are overlapping in a normal way.

Am I missing a text style props that would fix this ?

**EDIT : ok i figured out what was the issue
I actually have 2 styles for each of my features, and I give them the same z index, which result in text style being above everything else.
My issue is now to find out how to give my feature the style 1 and style 2 the z index X, and style 1 need to be over the style 2 ...**

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30332948/openlayers-3-image-and-text-style-zindex

Comment: I tried it, this is not working for me :( even if i'm adding +1 or anything with the         this.iconLayerStyles.iconStyle.setZIndex(icon.tag_id)
I'm explicitly giving a z index to each of my style, but the text style is not minding

Comment: Something like this.  Blue odd numbers are above orange even numbers, within the groups low numbers are stacked above higher numbers https://codesandbox.io/s/cluster-forked-yyu4w?file=/main.js

Comment: I major issue i'm facing now it that i'm seeing diferent zIndex on each of my feature, and I still have fontAwesome text symbol being above everything else... i console logged every getZindex and every feature has different one

Comment: Do you have the style set on each feature?  If so if you update it for one it updates for all.    There should be no style set on the feature, just update it in a style function as each feature is rendered

Comment: Actually, i'm creating an empty style object with 2 keys, iconStyle and bulletStyle, and then, i'm using setStyle on each of them depending on feature properties. If this, setStyle that. In the end of the function, I setStyle the feature with the final style + the zindex    ```this.iconLayerStyles.bulletStyle.setZIndex(2 + index * 10)
        this.iconLayerStyles.iconStyle.setZIndex(1 + index * 10) ``` and this for every feature.

Comment: If features share bulletStyle and iconStyle all features will use the most recent setting.  Either use a style function to set the zIndex as features are rendered, or clone the styles so they are not shared (which will use more resources).

Comment: Ok I created my styleFunction, returning conditionnal stuff dependind feature props, and then returning an array of 2 styles (icon et bullet) where I setted different zIndex (1/2 + id * 10), but I still get text above all ?